# How to Clear Triggered Control Template

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0, triggers, controltemplate

I am trying to achieve the "hint text" functionality for a TextBox in WPF. I can set the default text fine, but the problem comes when I want the control to return its appearance to a normal TextBox. Here is the trigger I have so far:

**Trigger A**

```
<Trigger Property="Text" Value="{x:Static sys:String.Empty}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                <TextBox>
                    <TextBox.Background>
                        <VisualBrush AlignmentX="Left" AlignmentY="Center" Stretch="UniformToFill">
                            <VisualBrush.Visual>
                                <Label Content="{TemplateBinding TextBox.Tag}" Background="White"/>
                            </VisualBrush.Visual>
                        </VisualBrush>
                    </TextBox.Background>
                </TextBox>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Trigger>
```

This sets the `Background` to a `VisualBrush` when the `Text` property is empty. What I need to do is clear this `ControlTemplate` when the user selects the `TextBox` to input text.

Here is what I tried:

**Trigger B**

```
<Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                <TextBox/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Trigger>
```

These two don't work together. I tested each by changing the `Background` colors. If I comment out either one, they will each work. If both are uncommented, Trigger A works and B is never seen. How can I remove/overwrite Trigger A?

I know that the functionality of these templates is supposed to clear when the trigger condition is no longer met, but for example, Trigger A's setting will not go away when I enter text into the `TextBox` like it should. Like the Text property is still `String.Empty` or something.

So what am I missing?

**EDIT:**

Here is the whole style (there's not much more to it):

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="FormsTextBox">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="45"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3 2 3 2"/>

        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Text" Value="{x:Static sys:String.Empty}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                            <TextBox>
                                <TextBox.Background>
                                    <VisualBrush AlignmentX="Left" AlignmentY="Center" Stretch="UniformToFill">
                                        <VisualBrush.Visual>
                                            <Label Content="{TemplateBinding TextBox.Tag}" Background="White" Width="45"/>
                                        </VisualBrush.Visual>
                                    </VisualBrush>
                                </TextBox.Background>
                            </TextBox>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot see whole template but this looks a bit overcomplicated. I assume you're trying to achieve watermark text. For hint use box standard [`ToolTip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.tooltip.aspx) property, which by default will display your text in a popup when hover your `TextBox` but this behaviour can be disabled and `ToolTip` property reused. You can either create reusable `Style` - which I prefer - for `TextBox`, something like this:

```
<Window ...>
   <Window.Resources>
      <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" x:Key="WatermarkTextBoxStyle">
         <Setter Property="ToolTipService.IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
         <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
               <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                  <Border Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}" 
                      BorderThickness="1" 
                      BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowFrameBrushKey}}">
                     <Grid>
                        <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0" 
                           Text="{TemplateBinding ToolTip}" 
                           Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Text.IsEmpty, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" 
                           Opacity="0.5"/>
                        <ScrollViewer Name="PART_ContentHost"/>
                     </Grid>
                  </Border>
               </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
      </Style>
   </Window.Resources>

   <TextBox ToolTip="watermark text" Style="{StaticResource WatermarkTextBoxStyle}"/>
</Window>
```

or, if it's a one-off thing, then do you can do something like this without any `Style` or `Template`:

```
<Grid Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}">
   <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0" 
      Text="watermark text" 
      Opacity="0.5" 
      Visibility="{Binding ElementName=myTextBox, Path=Text.IsEmpty, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
   <TextBox Name="myTextBox" Background="Transparent" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Wow, it works! Thank you. So... why does it work when my attempt doesn't? The main differences I see between your code and mine is the `Trigger` vs. `Visibility` and what we're using for our `ControlTemplate`.

Comment: Looking at your edit you're setting `TextBox` as `Template` of your `TextBox` and that will not work as it is different `TextBox`. Template for `TextBox` has [`PART_ContentHost`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752068(v=vs.110).aspx) named part which needs exact same name in your template in order so control can bind to it and able you to input text. So instead `TextBox` in `ControlTemplate` put in `ScrollViewer` with `x:Name="PART_ContentHost"`, like in my example, and change background of that